# Is there any package in python that can identify similarity between alphanumeric alias names of a parameter?

Tags: python, nltk

For example: for a parameter like input voltage,

```
     Alias names : V_INPUT, VIN etc.
```

Now, I want the software to recognize each of the alias names as same. Is there any package/method by which I can achieve this?

Nltk is only allowing for dictionary words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know there are only specific variants, you can obviously make a look-up table yourself (i.e. a Python dictionary).

Otherwise you could try using a fuzzy matching library, like [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy).

This will give you a "closeness" score for your search term, based on your list of parameters (measurements). Here is an example of how you could use it:

```py
In [1]: from fuzzywuzzy import process

In [2]: measurements = ["Voltage", "Current", "Resistance", "Power"]

In [3]: variants = ["VOLT", "voltage_in", "resistnce", "pwr", "amps"] # notice typos etc.

In [4]: for variant in variants:
   ...:     results = process.extract(variant, measurements, limit=2)
   ...:     print(f"{variant:<11} -> {results}")  # See which two were found to be closest 
   ...:     best = results[0]                     # Take the best match by score (first in the list)
   ...:     if best[1] < 70:                      # Set a threshold at 70%
   ...:         print(f"Rejected best match for '{variant}': {best}")

VOLT        -> [('Voltage', 90), ('Current', 22)]
voltage_in  -> [('Voltage', 82), ('Resistance', 30)]
resistnce   -> [('Resistance', 95), ('Current', 38)]
pwr         -> [('Power', 75), ('Current', 30)]
amps        -> [('Voltage', 26), ('Resistance', 22)]
Rejected best match for 'amps': ('Voltage', 26)
```

So most worked out pretty well, including the typo example.

Obviously this does not kind of `semantic` search, as so `amps` do not get related to `Current` in any way.

---

To go the way of semantic encodings, you might want to look into "word embeddings", which do indeed try to match the real meaning of words, based on their semantic meaning. To start here, you could look into `Word2Vec` or GloVe` embeddings. Perhaps there is even a tool or library that already offers this capability.

These approaches will not inherently deal with things like typos, so for best results, you could even combine the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks @n1k31t4. But can you explain how word embeddings can help here as the variants are alphanumeric?

Comment: Do you mean the parameter names like `V_INPUT` may also contain numbers? They are all strings anyway, so it wouldn't mean you can't use word embeddings. The problems, or extra hurdle, in your case is rather that you have words (tokens) that are not standard English. This means there won't likely be an existing set of embedding you use for parameter names such as `V_INPUT`. Unfortunately, that means you would probably need to create them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a couple.  My favorite is PyDictionary
[PyDictionary](https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/)

Or if you’re using pip make sure you’re up to date and in terminal execute this command:
`pip install PyDictionary` Hope this helped

Comment: This should also work in most IDLE s’